# How to customize bootstrap colors in a table

Tags: html, css

I created a CRUD system and am trying to customize it to make it look better using Bootstrap.

Currently I have the table striped with the "`table-striped`" class, however, I am trying to change the thead to a different color as I am not a fan of the options given, dark or light.

I also tried using CSS to customize it, but the browser doesn't seem to be loading the CSS even though it says it is linked in the sources.

```html
<table class="table bg-light table-striped table-bordered table-hover rounded">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>PO Number</th>
      <th>Site Name</th>
      <th>Date Created</th>
      <th>Last Updated</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($data['records'] as $row): ?>
    <?php if(isset($data['flash']['id']) && (int) $row['id'] === $data['flash']['id']): ?>
    <tr class="table-success">
      <?php else: ?>
      <tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td>
          <?= $row['id'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $row['poNum'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $row['site_name'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $row['created_at'] ? (new DateTime($row['created_at']))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : '' ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $row['updated_at'] ? (new DateTime($row['created_at']))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : '' ?>
        </td>
        <td>

          <a href="edit.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>&page=<?= $data['currentPage'] ?>"><img src="img/pencil-square.svg" title="edit" alt="edit" /></a>
          <?php if ($_SESSION['userRole'] === 'ADMIN'): ?>
          <a onclick="return confirm_delete(<?= $row['id'] ?>);" href="delete.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>&page=<?= $data['currentPage'] ?>"><img src="img/trash.svg" class="spacer" title="delete" alt="delete" /></a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this style:

```
th {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

I don't know how you test the CSS, but make sure it works by first using the CSS Internal. Put this code in the `<head>` tag and test if your CSS code works.

```
<style type="text/css">
th {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
} 
</style>
```

After you make sure that it works, just transfer the code to an external CSS file.

If the CSS doesn't take effect, try to figure out if it's not overwritten by another CSS somewhere by looking in the browser's developer console.

So you can try this:

```
.rounded th {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

You can also use `!important` but it's a good practice to not use this `!important` keyword as it may cause some conflicts somewhere else.

```
th {
        background-color: blue !important;
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: I tried the bottom one and this changed the text color to white. I changed it to thead which then made the background of thead blue. However, when i put this in the external css file it does not work

Comment: So make sure the address of the CSS file is ok when you are using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./some.css">` in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: The code is clearly in the source file correctly when it is loaded up

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overview.css" >

Comment: can you share the CSS file codes and also the `<link>` tag? you should not use `<style type="text/css">` tag in the CSS file, if you do so try to remove it. if not share the CSS file. also to test if the CSS file is loaded correctly just use this style `body{background: red;}` to totally sure the CSS file works correctly the body background should be red now.

Comment: Basically, i have a few content pages and each of them have a function called "extra_css" and a $css php variable that would connect the css file. I can see that the file is loaded in correctly but doesnt seem to load the CSS. I have a gitHub, so i will show you all the code i have in that, You would just need to go to overview.css and overview.phtml. I just need to upload the newest version

Comment: https://github.com/jacklythgoee/SiteSurvey

Comment: It was a  good practice not to share all your code. if you shared the `overview.css` files in the question and the code you tried we could know this is a conflict. but as you are new to this community. I reviewed your GitHub. but make sure to ask wisely in the future :). good luck and mark the answer as a true one if it solved your problem.

Comment: And another tip for your project. use a `.htaccess` file to forward all requests to `public/index.php` file that makes it better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I did just try this and it still didnt work sadly :/

Comment: did you put this `.rounded th {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
} ` into `overview.css`? I run your project and test it. it works fine for me. try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: ahh yes. I am using incognito so assumed it wouldn't save the cache. Guess it does sometimes

Comment: I would upvote your posts. but i dont have enough rep haha

Comment: Upvoting is not important. it's better to make the answer a true one. as you are the owner of the question. by the way, is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes this is solved.

Comment: Ok glad to hear that. and try to be friends with the browser developer console it's so helpful full find this kind of CSS problem. good luck

Comment: Yeah, i was confused on what the problem was. I could see that the file was being added to the .phtml but wasn't appearing any changes.